# Args cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I am getting an "args cannot be resolved to a variable" error for my picture outline code in Dr.java where I put stars.

```
public void faceOutline () {

    String filename;

    **if (args.length > 0)** {
      // got a filename passed into program as a runtime parameter
      **filename = args[0]**;      
      System.out.println("Filename passed in: " + filename);

    } else {
      // ask user for a picture
      filename = FileChooser.pickAFile();
      System.out.println("User picked file: " + filename);
    }

    // use the filename to create the picture object
    Picture pic = new Picture(filename);

    //show picture
    pic.show();

    //create world and turtle
    World w = new World();
    Turtle tj = new Turtle(w);

    tj.setPenWidth(7);
    tj.setPenColor(Color.red);
}
```

I was wondering how I could resolve this and how `args` work.

Comment: you've got a compiler error? Can't understand you problem, sorry

Comment: Please add the stacktrace. You may have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the question. Where exactly is your issue? You may also have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Sorry about being unclear, let me repost with detailed error information.

Comment: I think `args` only exists in the `main` function

Comment: @JeD no, `args` exists in any function where you define it (by one of quite a number of ways - local variable, parameter, member variable, static variable, static variable statically imported from another class; I may have missed others). It's just like any other variable - it is mere convention that it is frequently called `args` in `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, but it isn't defined. It should be a parameter passed to the programm, so I think the problem is that the function above should be a main function, but was copied into another function where `args` is not passed.

Comment: Can you change `public void faceOutline()` to `public void faceOutline(String[] args)` and then call it as `someObject.faceOutline(args)` from `main`?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your main method. As you will see, you can use `args` in your main method because it is passed as a parameter. So you should pass it to your new method too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: Thanks man, I fixed the compiling error immediately. I hadn't noticed that I could just pull it from the main method.